# Xcode 8 failed to locate or generate matching signing assets

Tags: xcode, codesign

I have officially exhausted all of the ideas on how to fix the issue one the screenshot. things I have done thus far:

1. Reinstalled the Apple WorldWide developer... cert to both system and login, and made sure it is always trusted
2. Deleted all developer certs from keychain
3. created a new product and selected automatically manage signing

I have dragged a few more Xcode projects (frameworks) such as Alamofire, FileKit, etc., I have embedded the frameworks.

Everything works fine until I try archiving and validating and get this error. I have the necessary profiles installed i think. Ideas

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I had to download a distribution profile manually from my developer account. Xcode didnt do it automatically.